# Calling StoredProcedure using JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to call a stored procedure, which is built in mysql, in my Spring boot app using JPA. My stored procedure returns the result which cant be contain in single model as it fetches data from combination of tables.
I can do this with "call " but i guess that is not JPA's way. COuld you please let me know what is the best way to do it?

Comment: JPA has its own Stored Procedure query API, which is there for calling such things, and no idea WHAT you are trying. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#stored_procedures

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using plain JPA you need to do a native query call. Something like below.

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select my_store_pro(?, ?)");
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

for (Object[] a : results) {
    System.out.println("result " + a[0] + " " + a[1]);
}
```

If you're using Spring Data repositories then you want something like below.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select my_store_pro(?, ?)")
Date callMyStoreProc(int val1, int val2);
```